# React-Native 0.52: Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I upgraded my project to React-Native 0.52.0 and React 16.2 from 0.51.0 and 16.0 and now when I try to run it using XCode (or via the CLI) I'm getting the following error:

[image]

The terminal output:

```
2018-01-20 06:19:16.972 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:210] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001c2850> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6040000c7620>, executor: (null))
2018-01-20 06:19:16.975378-0800 LevelStory[67373:2037856] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001c2850> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6040000c7620>, executor: (null))
2018-01-20 06:19:17.158 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:120] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2018-01-20 06:19:17.158401-0800 LevelStory[67373:2037856] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2018-01-20 06:19:17.215 [warn][tid:main][RCTModuleData.mm:69] Module RCTImageLoader requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2018-01-20 06:19:17.215060-0800 LevelStory[67373:2037856] Module RCTImageLoader requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2018-01-20 06:19:17.231 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:302] Running application LevelStory ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2018-01-20 06:19:17.231250-0800 LevelStory[67373:2037856] Running application LevelStory ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2018-01-20 06:19:17.345 [error][tid:NSOperationQueue 0x6040000355a0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)][RCTCxxBridge.mm:419] Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details (null))
2018-01-20 06:19:17.346054-0800 LevelStory[67373:2038114] Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details (null))
```

I've tried deleting and re-installing the node_modules folder, cleaning the cache, cleaning out watchman, relinking libraries to no avail. I'm having the same problem with a brand new project created using react-native init.

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 9.4.0
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.3871768

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: 0.52.0 => 0.52.0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React-Native doesn't work with Node v9.4.  Needed to downgrade to Node v8.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  This was the actual cause of my particular problem. Changing just the node version resolved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me even on Node v6.1.3

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. `sudo lsof -i :<Your port>`
2. Run `sudo kill -9 <PID>`
3. Downgrade Node to version 8
4. Run the application again

Comment: This worked for me on Node v10.7.0 when skipping step 3.